# How to export large archive table as CSV with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csv

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application that talks to a MS SQL Server Epress database with EF6. In the DB, we have a large archive table with >10 mio. rows. The archive table is relatively simple, just a handful of id's, a value and a timestamp.

I already have a "working" controller method that fetches the data from my DbContext as a IQueryable of my archiveEntry entity, then puts it into a List with .ToList(), creates a CSV file from that, zips it and then returns it to the client as a file download. The problem is, however, that it is way too slow for the whole table, with 250000 rows this takes about 15 minutes.

Is there a way to query and create the CSV right in the database and pass that right through to the client?

Comment: 15 mins is the whole time. What is the time to grab ONLY the data ? I think that on "SQL Server format" or "CSV Format" same quantity of data must be passed from SQL to ASP.Net

Comment: Do you have to use entity here? Bypassing the object interface (with SSIS or bcp for example) will really improve your time.

Comment: You can write a [CLR scalar function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I've had this issue before.  It is much quick to use sqlcmd.exe which is meant to archive databases and runs much quicker than the query in c# (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)  You can specify the output as csv.  I usually create a bat file from c# and then run the bat as a process.  You can also just use Process and the c# query statement is a parameter to sqlcmd.  A query in c# that was taking over 1/2 hour ran using sqlcmd.exe in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to bring down the time from many minutes to 2 seconds with these steps:

First, I disable some settings in my context (named "db") configuration:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Then, I run a raw SQL query on my database:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ValueArchive>("select * from ValueArchive").ToList();
```

And in the end I noticed that building the CSV string was massively improved by using a StringBuilder rather than adding new lines to a String variable.

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel, there are tons of good csv writer. You ll have to handle lot of problems (Encoding, Special chars)

Answer (score 6):

You can replace EF to read your entities by something faster like 'Dapper'.

More infos here : https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper

Another way, if you want to keep EF is to disable change tracking from your context (because you are just reading your entities)

You have two options for this :

1. `myContext.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`
2. `var logs= myContext.Logs.AsNoTracking();`

Then use a high performance CSV writer:

This one is pretty good : https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: A bit over the top in my case, but +1 for getting to know dapper, it looks interesting for some other projects!